# Plot longitudinal data in R with mean and SD

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I need to represent the delta changes for a huge amount of different variables.
I have been using Prism, using XY tables where each point is defined by an X and Y coordinate and where the Y has several replicate values in side-by-side subcolumns.

I am wondering how could I do this with R. So I don´t have to copy paste the data into `Prism`. I need to create a code that I can run every time (a loop is not necessary).

Here is my subset:

```
PatientID  Group  Visit   Delta
1OD         HC       1         0
1OD         HC       2         0.9
1OS         HC       1         0
1OS         HC       2         0.1
23OD        Patient  1        0
23OD        Patient  2        0.09
23OD        Patient  3        0.08
23OS        Patient  1        0
23OS        Patient  2        0.02
23OS        Patient  3        0.03
44OD        Patient  1        0
44OD        Patient  2        0.03
44OD        Patient  3        0.03
44OD        Patient  4        0.03
44OS        Patient  1        0
44OS        Patient  2        0.03
44OS        Patient  3        0.02
44OS        Patient  4        0.01
3OD         HC       1        0
3OD         HC       2        0.7
3OS         HC       1        0
3OS         HC       2        0.9
```

Example of the table from Prism: where Visits are in the X-axis.  `A= HC, B= Patients`

[image: This is an example of the table that I have in Prism]

Example of the two graphs that I want to get from R: 
The first one has mean and SD bars, the second one represents every subject

[image]

[image]

I would really appreciate your help!! :) 
Thanks 
Lili

PS_ I've tried too:

```
if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("kassambara/ggpubr")

install.packages("ggpubr")

library(ggpubr)

df$Visit <- as.numeric(df$Visit)
visit<- df$Visit

ggline(df, x = "visit", y = "Delta", add = c("mean_se", "jitter"), color = "Group", palette = "jco")
```

But it gives me an error:

> Error in [.data.frame`(data, , x) : undefined columns selected

Comment: @Eric Fail Could you help?

Comment: Looks like your `df`'s column is called `Visit` but you're trying to select `visit` (lowercase). Does that help?

Comment: @hdkrgr That is not the problem. It didn't recognise the variable Visit first and that's why I named it again :S

Answer (score 1):

Your grouping variable is called “Group.” and not “Group”. You are missing a dot.
Does this help?

Comment: SORRY! this was a error in my trascription of the database. I have edited the post.  But well spotted thanks